# Azure Active Directory as simply user/role validation service

Tags: azure-active-directory

Our current process is BizTalk expose a web service for vendor to call in, where the request header contains pre-assigned user name and password. Upon receiving service call, BizTalk validates the credential against the database, extract and attach some metadata from db record to the inbound message (e.g. city, vendor level etc)

Question,

1. can we replace this process with Azure Active Directory? Heard it does provide a restful API, but get confused everytime reading the documentation when talk about JWT token... Does it have a straight forward restful endpoint to call to validate and extract user information?
2. can we customize the metadata within the AAD user?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 - sure you can. There is no endpoint to perform validation, but it's easy to validate incoming tokens - we offer components that automate it. See https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet for an example. The same location on guthub has lots of other samples demonstrating different scenarios.

## 2 - I am not certain I understand what you mean with metadata here. If you are referring to the info you can specify about the user: you can customize the user scheme. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn720459.aspx

Comment: thanks! Definitely helps, will take a look.  However, in our case, we really just want to call AAD to validate user credential, not to call some webservice secured by AAD, to start with, we don't have a URL per se, how do we register the app, native or web?

Comment: If you configure your web site or web app to accept AAD tokens, at some point during access AAD will PPP its ux and verify credentials. Then, your app will receive a token - which is much easier for you to verify than credentials. That's the essence of the game :) see the readme of the sample I linked to for instructions on registration